# Assigning Intents to Strings in a Listview - No enclosing instance of ListActivity is accessible in scope

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

This is the code:

```
public class BookingActivity extends Activity {
static final String[] StrValues = new String[] { "Resturant", "Hotell" };
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitybooking);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, StrValues));


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, eksempelActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Resturant", StrValues);
    ListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
      });

  }
```

}

and im receiving this error:  **No enclosing instance of the type ListActivity is accessible in scope**

I have imported the necessary imports including the listactivy and AdapterView.OnItemClickListener. I've even tried to change the setonitemclicklistener-method to onitemclicklistener, but with 0 result.

Comment: this is not needed `ListActivity.this.`, just call `startActivity(myIntent)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a copy-paste mistake. Since your code is in an activity named `BookingActivity`, it makes little sense to reference a `ListActivity`. The latter - if it exists within your project, or one of its dependencies - is out of scope for the relevant code, hence the error.

In other words, to get rid of the error, replace all occurrences of:

```
ListActivity.this
```

with:

```
BookingActivity.this
```